# jQuery - Button CSS Class Reset after 2 Clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

On button first click, it should apply `.btn-1` class, second click `.btn-2` class and on Third click it should clear the `.btn-1` and `.btn-2` classes...
Till here, I am able to achieve this.

But If I click on the same button again, above functionality is **not repeating**.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wc6gLzts/)

**HTML**

```
<button class="dealbutton">Hello</button
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dealbutton").one("click", dealbuttonfn);
    function dealbuttonfn() {
        $(".dealbutton").addClass("btn-1");
        $(".dealbutton").one("click", function(){
            $(".dealbutton").removeClass("btn-1");
            $(".dealbutton").addClass("btn-2");
            $(".dealbutton").one("click", function(){
                $(".dealbutton").removeClass("btn-2");
            });
        });
}});
```

**CSS**

```
.dealbutton{height:200px;width:200px;background:#efefef;border:1px solid #aaa;color:#000;cursor:pointer;}
.dealbutton:focus{outline:none;}
.dealbutton.btn-1{background:#222;color:#fff;}
.dealbutton.btn-2{background:#444;color:#fff;}
```

Comment: When referring to `.dealbutton` inside `dealbuttonfn` function, you can use `this`. For example: `$(this).addClass("btn-1")`.

Comment: IMO you should use a counter to track subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use another valuable to loop on your classes 
my code :-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $(".dealbutton").on("click", dealbuttonfn);
    function dealbuttonfn() {
        $(".dealbutton").removeClass("btn-"+i);
        i++;
        if(i>3)
            i=1;
        $(".dealbutton").addClass("btn-"+i);        
        
       
    }
});
```

```css
.dealbutton{height:200px;width:200px;background:#efefef;border:1px solid #aaa;color:#000;cursor:pointer;}
.dealbutton:focus{outline:none;}
.dealbutton.btn-1{background:#222;color:#fff;}
.dealbutton.btn-2{background:#444;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="dealbutton">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically didn't like your approach build my own.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dealbutton').on('click', function () {
        var clickCount = parseInt($(this).data('count')) || 1; // Save click count on element itself
        clickCount %= 3; // loop over

        if (clickCount === 1) {
            $(".dealbutton").addClass("btn-1").removeClass('btn-2');
        } else if (clickCount === 2) {
            $(".dealbutton").addClass("btn-2").removeClass('btn-1');
        } else {
            $(".dealbutton").removeClass('btn-2 btn-1');
        }

        $(this).data('count', ++clickCount); // Update click count
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wc6gLzts/3/

Comment: Excellent @Tushar.. Its working perfectly... all above examples are having some problems if I click faster or 2nd time click etc...

Answer (score 0):

I also did it a bit different but it still follows the basic of your creation

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".dealbutton").bind('click', dealbuttonfn);
    function dealbuttonfn() {
        var button = $('.dealbutton');
        if(button.hasClass("btn-1 btn-2")) {
            button.removeClass("btn-1 btn-2");
        }
        else if(button.hasClass("btn-1")) {
            button.addClass("btn-2");
        } else {
            button.addClass("btn-1");
        }
    }
```

});

## demo

https://jsfiddle.net/wc6gLzts/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/wc6gLzts/5/), using [return false](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) to execute the function vice versa.

```
$(".dealbutton").click(function() {        
        $(this).addClass('btn-1');
    $(".btn-1").click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-1');
        $(this).addClass('btn-2');
    })
    $('.btn-2').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-2');
    })
    return false;
})
```